# OpenVZ sharing PHP5-FPM socket

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, mount, fastcgi, openvz

I need a problem with sharing php5-fpm.sock between 2 vz containers
I have 2 containers:
1. with NGINX
 
2. with PHP5 and PHP5-FPM

Link containers over NFS

I tried using:
1. mount --bind /var/lib/vz/private/100/var/src_dir_with_socket /var/lib/vz/private/101/var/dst_dir_with_socket
2. moutn -t simfs ...
3. pure NFS
for sharing php5-fpm.sock on NGINX container - does not work

Scheme to work only when I mount FPM at port
I need to work through SOCKET

Thx!

Comment: you need a problem?

Comment: Why would you like to share a socket? You're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can't share a UNIX domain socket between two different virtual machines.

In the particular case of OpenVZ, you can't share a UNIX domain socket between VEs without special kernel patches to break the security. From searching the Internet I see that such [patches were written several years ago](https://bugzilla.openvz.org/show_bug.cgi?id=985), but there's no indication of whether they have been kept up to date.

If you *really* want to do this, you should seek help in an OpenVZ support channel. This is not a recommended configuration.